# Postfix SMTP server: Emails not being queued for retry when greylisted [submission by email clients]

Tags: email, postfix

I have recently configured my own postfix server, however there is one thing left that's stumping me.

When sending emails via thunderbird to a server with greylisting enabled, I am instantly receiving a message stating that it is unable to send, rather than be put into a queue and attempt to send later.

I assume this would also have ramifications if I try to send to an email server that's having issues.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable submission port (port 587) in master.cf
   http://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-enable-port-587-submission-in-postfix/
2. Double check that submission port accepts emails only after successful **SMTP AUTH**
3. Turn off greylisting for messages received via submission port
4. Make your email clients send messages via submission port